# how to open a different link when clicking on dropdown and open the dropdown menu only when clicked on caret symbol in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, dropdown

In navbar I want to open a different page when I click on the "Dropdown" and open the dropdown menu only when I click on the caret symbol. For exmple in the code snippet below I want to open a new html page when I click on Dropdown and only open dropdown menu when I click on caret.How do I achieve this?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data- 
    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split button dropdown in bootstrap 4..

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns